# Process multiple dataframes in parallel Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql

I am a newbie in Scala-Spark. I have a dataframe like the one below that I need to split into different chunks of data based into a group ID and process them independently in parallel.

```
+----+-------+-----+-------+
|user|feature|value|groupID
+----+-------+-----+-------+
|   1|    100|    1|      A|
|   2|    20B|    0|      B|
|   3|    30A|    1|      B|
|   4|    40A|    1|      B| 
|   5|    50A|    1|      A|
|   6|    10A|    0|      B|
|   7|    200|    1|      A|
|   8|    30B|    1|      B|
|   9|    400|    0|      A|
|  10|    50C|    0|      A|
+----+-------+-----+-------+
```

**1 Step**  I need to split it to have two different df like these ones: I can user a filter for this. But I am not sure if (due to the large number of different dataframes they will produce) I should save them into ADLS as parquets or keep them in memory.

```
+----+-------+-----+-------+
|user|feature|value|groupID
+----+-------+-----+-------+
|   1|    100|    1|      A|
|   5|    50A|    1|      A|
|   7|    200|    1|      A|
|   9|    400|    0|      A|
|  10|    50C|    0|      A|
+----+-------+-----+-------+

+----+-------+-----+-------+
|user|feature|value|groupID
+----+-------+-----+-------+
|   2|    20B|    0|      B|
|   3|    30A|    1|      B|
|   4|    40A|    1|      B| 
|   6|    10A|    0|      B|
|   8|    30B|    1|      B|
+----+-------+-----+-------+
```

**2 Step** Process independently each dataframe in a parallel fashion and get independent processed dataframes.

To give some context:

- The number of groupIds will be high therefore they cannot be hardcoded.
- The processing of each dataframe would ideally happen in parallel.

I ask for a brief idea on how to proceed: I have seen .par.foreach (but is not clear to me how to apply this on a dynamic number of dataframes and how to store them independently nor if the best efficient way)

Comment: I am sort of curious as to why it needs to be done explicitly. DF partitions are processed in parallel anyway. .par I am wondering if you not eat your own resources (from hearsay and here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----+-------+-----+-------+
|user|feature|value|groupID|
+----+-------+-----+-------+
|1   |100    |1    |A      |
|2   |20B    |0    |B      |
|3   |30A    |1    |B      |
|4   |40A    |1    |B      |
|5   |50A    |1    |A      |
|6   |10A    |0    |B      |
|7   |200    |1    |A      |
|8   |30B    |1    |B      |
|9   |400    |0    |A      |
|10  |50C    |0    |A      |
+----+-------+-----+-------+
```

Get `distinct` groupid values from dataframe.

```
scala> val groupIds = df.select($"groupID").distinct.as[String].collect // Get distinct group ids.
groupIds: Array[String] = Array(B, A)
```

Use `.par` for parallel process. You need add your logic inside `map`.

```
scala> groupIds.par.map(groupid => df.filter($"groupId" === lit(groupid))).foreach(_.show(false)) // here you might need add your logic to save or any other inside map function not foreach.., for example I have added logic to show dataframe content in foreach.
+----+-------+-----+-------+
|user|feature|value|groupID|
+----+-------+-----+-------+
|2   |20B    |0    |B      |
|3   |30A    |1    |B      |
|4   |40A    |1    |B      |
|6   |10A    |0    |B      |
|8   |30B    |1    |B      |
+----+-------+-----+-------+

+----+-------+-----+-------+
|user|feature|value|groupID|
+----+-------+-----+-------+
|1   |100    |1    |A      |
|5   |50A    |1    |A      |
|7   |200    |1    |A      |
|9   |400    |0    |A      |
|10  |50C    |0    |A      |
+----+-------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: How could I save the processed df individually keeping somehow the groupID identifier to differentiate each df ? (the groupID column is lost during the transformation) I tried `groupIds.par.map(groupid => df.filter($"groupId" === lit(groupid)).groupBy("user").pivot("feature").agg(first($"value")).write.parquet("path"))` but when I read this parquet file with `spark.read.parquet("path")` I only get one dataframe instead of two

Comment: You can pass that column throughout your transformation logic till end & then use that column as partition

Comment: yes, you can do that.  while saving you need to append groupid to your hdfs path, so that path will be unique each thread will be writing data specific path only.

Comment: I finally used: groupIds.par.map(groupid => df.filter($"groupId" === lit(groupid))).groupBy("build_no").pivot("code").agg(first($"rating")).write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(path + "/" + groupid)